# Android IOIO board controlling Android's Music Player

Tags: android, android-music-player, ioio

I have connected two buttons to Android IOIO board. They work fine. But here is the question: How do I use these buttons as Next/Previous Song when Music Player is running and playing music. Are here any ideas?

Comment: why cant you create a new custom Mplayer to act accordingly?

Comment: Yes, will do so, I just wanted to know if there is any possibility to control process from "outside world".